# Debugging a VC++ multithreaded app

Tags: multithreading, debugging, visual-c++, deadlock

What tools can I use to debug a multithreaded visual c++ application? Can I get a graph or an image of the threads or detect thread errors? I have a deadlock on a `EnterCriticalSection` call and I can't figure out where it stems from.

Comment: I would start by getting a hang dump and running it through [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40336)'s Crash/Hang Analysis. It will generate a report which should tell you which threads are in contention for which critical sections. After that, you can use your debugger of choice, be it [windbg](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/11/hangs-and-how-to-solve-them-part-1-deadlocks.aspx) or Visual Studio, to look at the stack frames of those threads and try to determine how the program may have gotten in that state.

Comment: The Debug + Windows + Threads debugger window should be your first stop.  It shows you the active threads and their call stacks.  You should be able to identify the specific thread that deadlocked.  And another one that got past its own ECS call and got stuck somewhere.